# Website title issue

Tags: html, wordpress, seo, google-search-console

I recently opened two websites, one is running on WordPress and one is a HTML website. On both of them I have the same issue.

I added the title like that:

```
<title>Main Keyword - Secondary Keyword - SiteName</title>
```

The title doesn't exceed 69 characters.

When I search for the website on Google, the title is displayed like that:

```
SiteName: Main Keyword - Secondary Keyword
```

The issue: "SiteName" is on the left followed by ":".

This can't be something from WordPress because as I told you I have the same issue on a pure HTML website. Any ideas, suggestions? I really appreciate any intervention.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi there, I tried but it seems to working fine plz have a look at the image http://imgur.com/l5ABOnT

Comment: Yes, in the browser tab it looks fine, but when you search for the website on Google it's displayed like I said.

Comment: It is not a duplicate because I couldn't find the answer there. There was a comment saying that probably Google hasn't indexed the page yet, well that's not true. I've changed the title and description and it was updated in Google too, but still I get the title to the left followed by ":"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

1) open your panel in
/wp-admin/options-general.php

Check my image (my painel is in portuguese) but you can see the input for title and  description

[image]

Comment: For the WordPress site, I am using Yoast SEO plugin, so I don't use the basic Site Title from WordPress.